# Storing traceroute data within a relational database

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, rdbms

Please ask for clarification if what I am saying doesn't make sense.

I am attempting to store traceroute data within a relational database, the structure of the traceroute data is as follows:

```
public class Traceroute  
{
    IPAddress origin; 
    IPAddress destination;  
    Collection<Hop> hops;  
}

public class Hop  
{  
     int[] times;  
     IPAddress here;  
     Hop previousHop;
     Hop nextHop;
}
```

Now what I am looking for is a relational way to store this data, what ends up happening is my database gets blown out significantly (in theory).  Is there a way to correctly, and by correctly I mean minimal space, to store traceroute data in a relational database and efficiently (quickly) query it?

**THEORETICAL TABLE STRUCTURE**

```
Traceroutes  
(  
    traceroute_id number,
    previousNode varchar2(200), --nullable  
    nextNode varchar2(200), --nullable  
    rtt_1 number,  
    rtt_2 number,  
    rtt_3 number,  
    currentNode varchar2(200)
)
```

Comment: Could you provide the table structure that you have created? What do you mean by "blown out"?

Answer (score 3):

There's can be no definitive answer to this question. There are a number of options you could choose. Purely relational you might come up with something like this (this won't compile/run, it's just to demonstrate)

```
TraceRoute (
    TraceRouteID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    OriginIP NVARCHAR,
    DestinationIP NVARCHAR
)

Hop (
    HopID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    TraceRouteID INTEGER, -- foreign key linking to TraceRoute table PK
    HopNumber INTEGER, -- this instead of storing previus and next nodes
    Time1 INTEGER,
    Time2 INTEGER,
    Time3 INTEGER,
    Host NVARCHAR
)
```

Notice here you don't need to store where each hop is in relation to each other. Every trace route request contains a number of hops which you can order by the hop number.

Next step would be writing queries to extract the information. See what the performance is like. If you're not happy then try tuning your database (index columns etc). If you're still not happy then merge the TraceRoute and Hop tables (sometimes a bit of duplication is OK).

Really you need to stop thinking theoretically and actually try it!

Comment: Well it isn't so much the theoretical thinking, someone decided to push this into an in memory structure that is next to impossible to query off of.